# beforeunload event not triggering in IOS Devices

Tags: javascript, ios

When user leave page without saving at that time i am using **beforeunload** to show **popup** that **if you leave then your changes may not be saved** so user can choose Leave or Stay but it is not triggering in IOS Device (Iphone, Ipad) so I am stuck in IOS devices.

```
var isSkipUnsavedChangePopup = false;
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        var confirmationMessage = "Are you sure want to leave?";
        if (!$("#btnSave").prop("disabled") && !isSkipUnsavedChangePopup) {
            (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
            return confirmationMessage;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using to do that.

Comment: I have added the code @ChristianFritz

Answer (score 0):

Use `unload` of jquery mobile this way

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});
```

here is doc: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/unload/index.html

Comment: I have modified the code.

$(window).on("unload", function() {
  alert('Handler for .unload() called.');
});

Now it Is blocked by browser and it shows error:  Blocked alert('Handler for .unload() called.') during unload.

Comment: @RhdayParikh that means it worked for you, is there any problem you are facing?

Comment: Yes, browser is blocking the popup. Event is triggering but popup is blocked even in chrome browser. I have to show popup in IOS devices.